# Firefox Shortcut Icon Text Not Capitalized

Tags: wordpress, firefox, shortcut

On Firefox, when my website's icon and site title are saved in my shortcuts, the site title is all lowercase and one word. I do not want to edit the text in Firefox.

Any suggestions what I can do on the Wordpress side to have the site title display on Firefox Shortcuts as two words with each first letter capitalized, Like This?

Comment: Working great on my side. Can you maybe share a screenshot and also show us the URL of your website (to see the source code generated).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the site titles that are capitalized are paid sponsors, everyone else seems to be lower case from their domain name.